# How to launch an List fragment activity from Normal activity using On Click of Button

Tags: android

I have created an App with many list fragments in it. It works really fine. I have an main Application in which I want to merge the new list fragment app. I have included activity in Android manifest as well. Below is my Main Activity of ListFragment App,  xml have three fragments and nothing else.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ctx1 = getApplicationContext();
}
```

In my Main App I have several buttons, which launches different Activities on Click.

How do I launch my list fragment using one of the button.

I did use:

```
Intent listactivity= new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestListFragmentMain.class);
        startActivity(listactivity);
```

But the above code gives me some inflating exceptions :( 
Is there a easy way to do this? 
Please reply

Trace Logs:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1478): GC_CONCURRENT freed 140K, 14% free 7493K/8707K, paused 13ms+0ms, total 76ms

D/AndroidRuntime( 1478): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm( 1478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa631d288)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.droidtv.TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp/org.droidtv.TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp.AndroidListFragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at org.droidtv.TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp.AndroidListFragmentActivity.onCreate(AndroidListFragmentActivity.java:18)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5098)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    ... 11 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment org.droidtv.VideoFeaturingTestApp.VideoFeaturingMainMenuClass: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1478):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Comment: You can't launch fragment with Intent. You can only do that with activities.
For fragment your activity must have container which will store fragment. It is very well explained in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: My Main file extends Activit , and i have only OnCreat method copied with the question. Will that not help ?

Comment: can you post stack trace of an exception?

Comment: I have edited my question with trace of exception

Comment: I might had missed a step , now when i did the whole thing again everything is working fine. Used normal Intent method to launch new activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might had missed a step , now when i did the whole thing again everything is working fine. Used normal Intent method to launch new activity